# Где правильнее хранить и передавать параметры фильтров на сервер в приложении на NextJS?

Tags: веб-программирование, reactjs, веб-сервер, ssr, nextjs

Всем привет! Разрабатываю веб-приложение на Next.js + GraphQL.

В качестве сервера использую ApolloServer + Express.
Фронтенд на Next.js + ApolloClient.

Использую как генерацию на сервере, так и в браузере.

На фронте у меня есть поисковая страница, на которой есть куча фильтров (чекбоксов). Как мне их передавать на сервер во время SSR? Думаю через куки? Но может быть есть еще какие-либо варианты?